# How to reload SimpleAdapter on onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. Screen 1 shows list data from server
2. User presses "+" button on top right to add a new item
3. Screen 2 shows with text field
4. User enters data and clicks save
5. Now I want to go back to Screen 1 and refresh the list from server so that the newly added item shows up

I'm having problems achieving point 5 above. This is what I have so far:

I have an `AyncTask` like following:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockListActivity {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> taskList;

//this grabs data from server and loads it in ArrayList
protected void loadList() {
    taskList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setServer("http://10.0.2.2:8080").build();
    final TaskService apiManager = restAdapter.create(TaskService.class);
    final Task task = apiManager.getTask("someuser", task_id);

    for (Item item : task.getItems()) {
        String t_id = t.getId()+"";
        String name = t.getName();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("act_id", act_id);
        map.put("t_id", t_id);
        map.put("t_name", name);
        taskList.add(map);
    }
}

public void onCreate (Bundle b) {
  new LoadItems().execute();
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle().equals("Create")) {
        Intent create = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateTask.class);
        startActivityForResult(create, 1);
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        //item got added now load again from server
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
            new UpdateItems.execute();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}

class UpdateItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        loadList();
        return null;
    }
}

class LoadItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
      loadList();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MyActivity.class, taskList,
                R.layout.list_item_rec, new String[] { "act_id", "t_id", "t_name"}, new int[] {
                R.id.act_id, R.id.t_id,R.id.t_name });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**Question**

How can I reload the data from the server in `onActivityResult`. Based on above, what I'm doing is creating another AynchTask only for loading the data again and then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This doesn't seem to be working.

Is my process wrong? Is there a better way to do this? I am stumped....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reload the data in `UpdateItems` `onPostExecute()` method..because you are loading data in `AsynchTask` it loads data in another thread and updating the `ListView` but the list is not loaded at that time..so change your `AsynchTask` like this..

```
class UpdateItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        loadList();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and remove this line  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onActivityResult()`

Comment: That helps clears things up. Also, now I'm noticing that when I click save buton to do a POST request on Screen 2, the GET request for data to go be displayed back on screen1 (`onActivityResult`) is getting called BEFORE the POST method. Because of which I'm not able to pick the recently added item. How should I be troubleshooting this? Is there a reson the a `onActivityResult` would be called BEFORE the actual intent is finished processing? This is how the create task looks like: https://gist.github.com/Omnipresent/7837863

Comment: are you added any flags for intent to screen2 ..with some flags onActivityResult called before..check once..

Comment: The only flag I'm using is `RESULT_OK`. It seems that the problem is that in gist.github.com/Omnipresent/7837863  I am doing the POST in `new CreateItemTask(...).execute()` and right after that returning the intent. So since `CreateItemTask` runs in a separate thread, the POST happens AFTER the intent is returned. Is there a way around this?

Comment: change this intent code to your onPostExecute() of CreateItemTask

Comment: But then How would I access `setResult()` since that method is part of `Activity` and not `AsyncTask`? I need to set result of `RESULT_OK` back to the original activity

Comment: Ohh..you are not taken it as a inner class..if it inner class you can..other wise pass your Activity object in AsynchTask constructor and initialize there and call activity.setResult(resultCode);.are you got it??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42696/discussion-between-omnipresent-and-kalyan-pvs)